# Remove dot after number php

Tags: php, regex

i have strings like "5./6." or just "3." . 
I want to remove dots after numers. how do i do this in php ?

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a free coding service, you know. Try something, if you can't get it to work, come back, show us what you've tried and we can help you from there.

Answer (score 2):

That's what [trim](http://php.net/trim) is for:

**Syntax:**

```
string trim (string $str, string $character_mask)
```

**Example:**

```
$string = "5./6.";
echo trim($string,'.');
```

---

**Update 1:** Remove all dots

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
$string = "5./6.";
echo str_replace(".", "", $string);
```

---

**Update 2:** Remove dots only after numbers and retain for text

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace)

```
$string = 'Random text 5./6. with. test 3. abc.. 234.. a'; 
echo preg_replace("/(\d)\.*/", "$1", $string);
```

Prints:

```
Random text 5/6 with. test 3 abc.. 234 a
```

Comment: and what abouty dot after 5 ? i need this removed as well

Answer (score 2):

> I want to remove dots after numbers.

Use `preg_replace` function:

```
$str = 'not a number, 10 5./6. 1000/2';  // extended example
$str = preg_replace("/(\d+)\./", "$1", $str);

print_r($str);
```

The output:

```
not a number, 10 5/6 1000/2
```

---

If there could be multiple dots `.` after a number, change the regex pattern to the following: `"/(\d+)\.*/"`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/(?<=\d)\.+/", "", $string);
```

This will remove dots that follow a digit.